# Undefined Method Error - Modifying a Hash in a Case Statement After

Tags: ruby

So, I made a hash called "facing". I call a case statement after, where I want to subtract 1 from the value if the user types L, or (I didn't get here yet) add 1 if the input = 'R'.

```
class Rover
  attr_accessor :orientation
end

#facing = Hash.new

facing = {
  0 => 0
}

bot = Rover.new
bot.orientation = "N"

puts "Bot's current orientation is: " + bot.orientation 
puts "What direction to turn ('L' or 'R')?"

input = gets.chomp.to_s.capitalize

case input
  when input = 'L'
    facing do |key, value|
      value - 1
    end
end
```

The problem is that I get a method undefined (facing) error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please look into the [Hash Object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)

Comment: You might want to look here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Ruby-Programming-Language-David-Flanagan/dp/0596516177/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1395882607&sr=8-7&keywords=ruby

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at the documentation for `case`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case).

This statement: `input = 'L'` means "give the variable `input` the value `'L'`", not "check if it equals 'L'".

But that's not where your error is coming from. With `facing do...` You're giving a block to a hash, which is confusing the compiler and causing it to look for a `facing` method.

What exactly are you trying to do with the hash?

Comment: I'm intending to keep a counter with the hash. I want the user to repeatedly input L or R until happy (and forward as well). I see the hash as a mathematical way to keep tabs on the bot's orientation. So, if the bot turns left, -1 to the Y value. That way, after, I can play with the last number given and return a value for the bot's orientation.

Comment: That's a bit of an odd use for a hash. Consider using a [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Struct.html) or just some instance variables on your Rover.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zach. I'd upvote you but I don't have enough rep yet. I'm still just learning the basics of Ruby.